# Create NSDictionary with order support

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

I need a `NSDictionary` object that not only support key->value storage but also support `key` sequence just like Array does.

Is there something exists on Objective-C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monolo's answer is the right way to do this.

`[self allKeys]` does not return ordered sequence. it's an `NSSet` style.

And I write a Class named `PLHash` that has many features:

- key value storage
- key order support
- items max size control ( set a maxItems to PLHash and it will keep items by FIFO )

here is the URL 
https://github.com/xhan/PlutoLand/blob/master/PlutoLand/Additions/PLHash.h

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built in, but you can use an array of keys along side the dictionary to record the order.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best off either getting the allkeys array and sorting that then getting the value for a key or making your own class to store objects the way you want them. It really sounds like you are doing something NSDictionary really wasn't built to do, what are you trying to do that you want the keys sorted?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a category on nsdictionary, call it sortedKeys or something, which returns a sorted [self allKeys].

Update:  Now that I'm not responding from my phone, here's my suggestion, written verbosely for clarity, and assuming you're using ARC:

```
@interface NSDictionary (sort)

- (NSArray *)sortedKeys;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary (sort)

- (NSArray *)sortedKeys {

    NSArray *keyArray = [self allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedKeyArray = [keyarray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    return sortedKeyArray;
}

@end
```

I personally don't think that subclassing NSDictionary is the way to go.